# How to type Enter so that it's considered as Enter command?

Tags: register

I have noticed that I can execute a command by yank, then `@"`.
My question is how do I make enter work within the command?

For example, when I yank `:w<Enter>`, I would like this command to be executed when I do`@"`.
More generally, how do I do this for other keys, such as `<Esc>,  <Control>, etc`?

Comment: @user907860 answers belong in answers, not comments, which are for clarification and feedback. See [what are comments, and when should I use them?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)

Comment: Luke, welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the actual terminal code of `<CR>` in your yanked text instead of the literal characters `<CR>`.

To input the terminal code in insert mode you need to use <kbd>ctrl+v</kbd> and then the key you want to input, here <kbd>Enter</kbd>. See [`:h i_CTRL-V`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-V)

So the text you will yank should look something like

```
:w^M
```

Once you yank it and use `@"` Vim will consider `^M` as the actual terminal code of <kbd>Enter</kbd> so it will simulate the key press and that will execute the command.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a line of text consisting of just `:w`, doing `yy` on that line will yank it into `@"` with the `<Enter>` character automatically. But with other control keys you would have to physically enter it on the line of text to be yanked.

Also `:set cpoptions+=>` Ensures that whatever is copied/appended to a register is terminated by ONE newline, even if it is only part of a line that is yanked.